# Extracting data out of Pandas df into a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, datetime, text-extraction

I have a Pandas dataframe with headers and rows that contain redundant data and wanted to extract from it. For example, I have a df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Your availability: Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM': ['Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM', pd.NaN, pd.NaN, 'Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM'],
                'Your availability: Tuesday, December 10th 2019 8:00AM-5:00PM': [pd.NaN, 'Tuesday, December 10th 2019 8:00AM-5:00PM', pd.NaN, pd.NaN]})
```

...and I want to extract the dates and put it into a dictionary for reference:

```
datetimes = {'P1': "Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM", 'P2' : "Tuesday, December 10th 2019 8:00AM-5:00PM", 'P3': NaN, 'P4': "Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try this

```
df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1].rename(lambda x: f'P{x+1}').to_dict()

Out[1159]:
{'P1': 'Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM',
 'P2': 'Tuesday, December 10th 2019 8:00AM-5:00PM',
 'P3': nan,
 'P4': 'Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want:

```
df.drop_duplicates().stack().to_list()
```

Output:

```
['Wednesday, December 25th, 2019 5:00AM-6:00AM',
 'Tuesday, December 10th 2019 8:00AM-5:00PM']
```